# Sonarqube scan with different java version than project

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a project which is written in java 8. It is kind of complex for me and very dependent to java 8. However I also happen to have a SonarQube and a Jenkins instance which is trying to use java 11 to scan the projects.

When java 11 is used to run:

```
mvn clean verify
```

I get java 8 dependency errors in the project and when I use java 8 I can not use sonarscanner.

I could not find and answer yet.

Any solution or suggestions ?

Comment: Sonarqube latest version is not compatible with JAVA 8 . So you need to downgrade the version of sonarqube and jenkins to run them as intented

Comment: @Umeshwaran I can not do that since the company bought it and installation is done.

Comment: There is no other workaround that I know of to achieve this . Sorry.

Comment: Are you using `sonar-maven-plugin` on Jenkins server to build and scan your project? If Jenkins only uses JDK11, how do you currently build your project?

Comment: @TasosP. Jenkins also uses java8 (and java 8 is default, usually) for project build, test and deploy however my problem starts when I try to integrate sonar scan to our legacy codes.

Comment: If you are using `sonar-maven-plugin` it would be trivial to run i.e. `mvn sonar:sonar` on Jenkins and use `sonar.host.url` of your SQ server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after creating a workaround for this I forgot to answer. That is on me.

Long story short, I installed seperate versions of Java to the instance. Re-write the pipeline and filled the terminal according to sonarqube scanner with env changes on sh blocks.

```
sh ''' export XXX=YYY  #key-value pairs for java, configs, mvn_home etc.
       export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/java-11/bin/java
       etc. '''
```

After that I defined a cleanup script to revert everything. I worked like a charm so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Jenkins instance (using JDK8) to build and submit the project to your SonarQube instance running on JDK11.

Using SonarQube's [recommended scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.9/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/) you can configure your project to use the remote SQ server:

`pom.xml`

```xml
<properties>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarqube.cldbz.net/</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

and then trigger the scanning process on Jenkins with `mvn sonar:sonar` which would submit your project's scan results to your SQ server.

You can even test this without `pom.xml` changes:

`mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=<token> -Dsonar.host.url=https://<sonar-server>:<port>`.